# Regular expression test can't decide between true and false (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I get this behavior in both Chrome (Developer Tools) and Firefox (Firebug). Note the regex test returns alternating true/false values:

```
> var re = /.*?\bbl.*\bgr.*/gi;
undefined
> re
/.*?\\bbl.*\\bgr.*/gi
> re.test("Blue-Green");
true
> re.test("Blue-Green");
false
> re.test("Blue-Green");
true
> re.test("Blue-Green");
false
```

However, testing the same regex as a literal:

```
> /.*?\bbl.*\bgr.*/gi.test("Blue-Green");
true
> /.*?\bbl.*\bgr.*/gi.test("Blue-Green");
true
> /.*?\bbl.*\bgr.*/gi.test("Blue-Green");
true
> /.*?\bbl.*\bgr.*/gi.test("Blue-Green");
true
```

I can't explain this and it's making debugging very difficult. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Funky. Reproduced w/ Firefox 3.5.8 and Firebug 1.5.3. Still occurs if "Blue-Green" is stored into a variable and re-used.

Comment: I found this to be mildly amusing.  Instead of using `a = !a` to switch between true/false, why don't we define a private regexp object and use `regexp.test!`

Comment: It's defined in the ECMAScript spec to behave like this, it'll be the same in all browsers.

Comment: Stops if you don't use /g

Edit: Ah, answer says why ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/g` (global) regexps will do that, yes.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630418/javascript-regex-returning-true-then-false-then-true-etc).

When you write a literal, you're getting a new regexp object every time, so losing the `lastIndex` state associated with the old object.

Comment: Nothing about the JavaScript `RegExp` interface makes any sense! The Real WTF is the properties on the global `RegExp` constructor object reflecting the last match... ugh.